# Import Vuetify components in your npm package without importing it again in other projects

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite, auto-import

I created a `npm package` for UI components by using `Vue 3`,`Vuetify 3` and `vite`.
You get warning When you use it in another project because it can not **read Vuetify's components!**
For solving that you can install `Vuetify` again in the  project that has been used in that package!.

The warning that I got in the project:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-btn
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

[image]

```
//package project : vite.config.js 

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import path from "path";
import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from "vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js";
import vuetify from "vite-plugin-vuetify";

import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { VuetifyResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), cssInjectedByJsPlugin(),
    Components({
      dirs: ['vuetify/es5/components', 'vuetify/es5/components/card'],
      extensions: ['vue'],
      resolvers: [VuetifyResolver()],
    }),

  //   vuetify({
  //   autoImport: true,
  //
  // })

  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@/": new URL("./src/", import.meta.url).pathname,
    },
    
  },

  build: {
    cssCodeSplit: true,
    target: "esnext",
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
      name: "GithubPackagesUiLibrary",
      fileName: (format) => `asdon.${format}.js`,
    },

    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue' , 'vuetify'],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue',
          vuetify: 'Vuetify',
          'vuetify/components': 'VuetifyComponents',
          'vuetify/directives': 'VuetifyDirectives'
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```
//package project : main.ts


import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "@/App.vue";
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'

import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import {VBtn} from "vuetify/components/VBtn";

export const myPlugin = {
    install(app:any) {
        app.component("v-btn", VBtn);


    }
}
createApp(App).use(vuetify).use(myPlugin).mount("#app");
```